# Why the router parameter is sometimes define in useEffect, sometimes not?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I hope you are doing well.
I pass a parameter in useEffect in react native but i don't know why sometimes when i use it he is undefined or another time he is defined.

I pass the parameter in navigation :

```
props.navigation.navigate("TicketsStack", {
                                        screen: "Ticket",
                                        params: {bookingSuccess: true},
                                })
```

The useEffect function is :

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let unsubscribe;
        unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener("focus", async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            console.log('booking : ', bookingSuccess);
            console.log('route : ', route);
            if (bookingSuccess) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setTicketScreen(false);
                }, 4000);
            } else {
                setTicketScreen(false);
            }
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [props.navigation, loadTickets]);
```

For retrieve my paramter I make :  `const bookingSuccess = props.route.params.bookingSuccess;`

Thanks all in advance for your help.

Comment: ```import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/core'```
Try to access properties via ```const route =  useRoute(); route.params.bookingSuccess;```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that too but it works some times and others not